# PHP Aura SQL, swithing database inside class

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am a bit puzzled here, I am easing myself into oop and struggling a little. I have beenusing Aura SQL (php) and have achieved pretty much what I need, but, it has become necessary to connect to more than one DB to update some legacy code I have been passed.

```
    class Core {
        public $pdo;
        private static $instance;

        private function __construct()  {

            $this->pdo = new ExtendedPdo(
                'mysql:host=localhost;charset=utf8;dbname=db',
                'user',
                'pass'
            );
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET NAMES utf8');
        }

        public static function getInstance() {
            if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
                $object = __CLASS__;
                self::$instance = new $object;
            }
            return self::$instance;
        }
    }
```

I have tried to amend by passing the values in via the constructor, but, it seems to be ignored eg:

```
   private function __construct($db_name)  {
      if !empty($db_name)) { $this->db = $db_name; } else { $this->db = 'default_db'; }

      $this->pdo = new ExtendedPdo(
            'mysql:host=localhost;charset=utf8;dbname='.$this->db.'',
    ....
```

Normally you would use getInstance(); but I have been trying instantiating a new object to access the other databases.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please checkout the [ConnectionLocator](https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Sql#connection-locator) via which you can create default connection, and rest of the connections. Taking code snippet from the readme.

```
<?php
use Aura\Sql\ConnectionLocator;
use Aura\Sql\ExtendedPdo;

// default connection
$default = function () {
    return new ExtendedPdo(
        'mysql:host=default.db.localhost;dbname=database',
        'username',
        'password'
    );
};

// read connections
$read = array(
    'slave1' => function () {
        return new ExtendedPdo(
            'mysql:host=slave1.db.localhost;dbname=database',
            'username',
            'password'
        );
    },
    'slave2' => function () {
        return new ExtendedPdo(
            'mysql:host=slave2.db.localhost;dbname=database',
            'username',
            'password'
        );
    },
    'slave3' => function () {
        return new ExtendedPdo(
            'mysql:host=slave3.db.localhost;dbname=database',
            'username',
            'password'
        );
    },
);

// write connection
$write = array(
    'master' => function () {
        return new ExtendedPdo(
            'mysql:host=master.db.localhost;dbname=database',
            'username',
            'password'
        );
    },
);

// configure locator at construction time
$connections = new ConnectionLocator($default, $read, $write);
$default_connection = $connections->getDefault();
$read_slave1_connection = $connections->getRead('slave1');
$read_any_connection = $connections->getRead();
$write_connection = $connections->getWrite();
```

Comment: Thank you Hari, only saw this after I had resolved. It will be useful though. Thanks again.